# Keil µvision 5 header file shows an error, however it is compiled without problems

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

I got access to this project. It is compiled in Keil µvision 5. When I compile the project it has no errors. However, when I access a header file it shows me an error, saying that **s8** variable has the following error = **error: unknown type name 's8'**.

```
    typedef struct
    {
      s8 str[PARAM_TEXT_SIZE];
    }
    text_struct;
```

The variable is defined as follow:

```
   typedef char   s8;
```

I wonder whether I have misconfigured the compiler, or why this error is neglected after compiling.

PS: This is my first question in the StackOverflow site. Sorry if my question is not clear or is wrongly placed.

Comment: Who defines the variable and where? Which files are these located in? `s8` is not standard. In addition, it is a very bad idea to typedef `char` as signed 8, since it can be unsigned. What you should do (since the year 1999) is to use `stdint.h` and not some home-made junk types.

Comment: @Lundin '(since the year 1999)' --> Since the year your cross-compiler provider realizes the 21st century is a thing. *cries in 198X*.
(ARM compiler is quite up-to-date anyway)

Comment: Hello @Lundin, as I have said I got this code. Normally, I would use as you said the 'stdint.h'. But, this is a big code ( over 100k code-lines), and this variable is widely used in the code. It is define in the 'typedef_arm.h' file for the arm microcontroller. And it is defined as signed variable because it matters for the binary computation of the microcontroller.

Comment: If this piece of code comes from a header it's totally possible that this header doesn't have the required include containing the typedef for `s8`, but the file that includes the one having this error does include it, so at compile time there's no problem but statically speaking the header is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `s8` is defined in a header, let's say `foo.h`, and your `text_struct` is defined in another header, call it `bar.h` then it compiles perfectly if the file that includes `bar.h` includes `foo.h` first. It is however not clean, it's usually a good practice not to rely on such pre-requisite includes.

Here's a very simple example :

**foo.h**

```
typedef int myType;
```

**bar.h**

```
typedef struct {
    myType x;
} myStruct;
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

myStruct y;

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile without issue, however if `bar.h` is statically evaluated then it'll produce an error since `myType` is not known here. If `bar.h` is included without `foo.h` to be included as well, then you'll have a compilation error. Here's an example :

**error.c**

```
#include "bar.h"

myStruct z;
```

> gcc -I. error.c -o error.o
>
> **In file included from error.c:1:0:
>   bar.h:2:5: error: unknown type name 'myType'**
>        myType x;

Comment: Hello @TimF, I appreciate your answer! However, I forgot to mention, the declaration of the header file is like this:
`#ifndef _PARAM_H`
`#define _PARAM_H`
`code`
`#endif`
I am not so acquainted with this type of declaration, so i do not know if I am allowed to declare a header file here.

Comment: Yes you are. This `PARAM_H` is just a guard that prevents you to include your header more than once. It's standard to put it on top of each header and it should have the capitalized name of your header + H. In my example it would be `_FOO_H` and `_BAR_H`. See [Include Guard on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). 
If my answer was useful don't hesitate to upvote and accept it. Welcome on StackOverflow by the way !

Comment: Thanks @TimF! Worked fine for me. Thanks for the warm welcome ! :)